# Distributing a Neo4j Graph Across Multiple Servers

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

Is it possible to distribute a Neo4j graph across multiple servers where vertex A on server 1 is edge-connected to vertex B on server 2?

All I can find so far are discussions on Neo4j's sharding but I can't find anywhere where it is specifically stated that edges can span servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way for a relationship to connect nodes on different servers.

If such a capability existed, it would be *significantly* slower than having all the data colocated, and also suffer a higher rate of query failure (due to things like timeouts and dropped connections).

Comment: Two questions... Why do you think it would be significantly slower and why do you think it would lead to a higher rate of query failures? I am conducting a product comparison between Neo4j and Objectivity/DB. Objectivity/DB allows a connected graph to span up to 65,000 servers, with a fully distributed query mechanism that can traverse the distributed graph. No sharding necessary.

Comment: 1. Accessing data over a network is much slower than accessing local data. Also, network connections can break or remote servers can go down. In addition, managing a single transaction across multiple servers is much harder. Yes, it is doable, but it will be slower and more error-prone. 2. I guess one could finesse it by actually storing a hidden local copy (a proxy) of the "remote" nodes and then try to propagate updates remotely in the background, but that would mean delayed consistency and may be more error-prone (and you'd lose storage to the hidden data).

Comment: "Accessing data over a network is much slower than accessing local data." - Agreed, but when you have a globally distributed application, co-locating a customer's local data with each business location makes sense, even when we are talking about cloud regions. We are all on the network. Neo4j's model means that none of my Hong Kong nodes can be connected to my New York nodes unless I put everything on one server and create a network inconvenience for all but one of my client locations.

Comment: Using neo4j [causal clustering](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/clustering/introduction/), all servers can have all the data, and the neo4j driver on a client will automatically pick a nearby server. Seems to be no need to split up the data. You can also use nearby read-replica servers to perform  read-only queries. Also, since a server will cache the data it accesses, nearby servers will naturally cache the data needed by nearby clients, improving the speed.

Comment: In one Objectivity/DB deployment a customer distributed their federated across tens of thousands of telecom devices spread across Europe. Each device contains its own piece of the larger  federation but the federation appears as a single large database to every viewer through Objectivity's "Single Logical View" technology. In many environments it is impractical to have thousands of full replicas to solve what is simply a distribution problem. The query capability fully distributed and does not require the application developer to do anything special to take advantage of it.

Answer (score 1):

The Neo4j Community Edition only supports single-node graph queries and cannot support distributed scenarios.

If you require distributed scenarios, I may recommend you GraphScope.
GraphScope is a fast, efficient, and highly scalable graph query system that supports distributing a graph across multiple servers. With GAIA-IR, the interactive graph query engine in GraphScope, you can easily incorporate various graph query languages like Cypher, Gremlin thanks to its unified intermediate representation layer.

Here is an example for graph querying in GraphScope:

```
import graphscope
sess = graphscope.session(num_workers=4)
graph = sess.g()
graph = graph.add_edges('/path/to/dataset')

interactive = sess.interactive(graph)
print(interactive.cypher('...'))
sess.close()
```

You could refer to this [article](https://blog.graphscope.io/gaia-ir-graph-interactive-query-engine-in-graphscope-340993f4637c) to learn the design of GAIA-IR and how it can be deployed and used.
Disclaimer: I'm an author of GraphScope.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, the Resource Description Framework (RDF) graph model [1] natively supports this type of functionality.  You can use the Federated Query functionality of the SPARQL 1.1 query language to query datasets across multiple RDF stores.

An example of this using a local dataset containing info on English Premier League football (soccer) clubs and combining this data with a publicly accessible RDF store (DBpedia):

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX soccer: <http://www.example.com/soccer#>

SELECT distinct ?nickName ?airportName ?cityName ?airportID {
    
    ?soccerTeam dbo:city ?city .
    ?soccerTeam soccer:nickname ?nickName .
    
    SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> {
        
        BIND ("LHR" as ?airportID) 
        
        ?airport dbo:iataLocationIdentifier ?airportID ;
                 dbo:city ?city ;
                 rdfs:label ?airportName .
        ?city rdfs:label ?cityName .
```

The `SERVICE` clause in SPARQL can be used to provide this means of federation.

Whether or not RDF would work for you depends on the types of queries that you need to ask of the graph.  Property Graph databases and query languages are typically better at retrieving a traversed path (all objects between start and finish).  SPARQL can traverse iteratively [2], but it can be non-trivial to express a query that retrieves all intermediary components of the traversal.

[1] https://www.w3.org/RDF/
[2] https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-property-paths/